# Unable to display data on rdlc report asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017, reportviewer

I'm using a stored procedure and details on a report. I'm using report viewer and dataset; however I just seem to be getting an error in aspx file:

> Error Creating Control - ReportViewer1Failed to create designer
>   'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer,
>   Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'

But when I execute it only shows this and no details on the report.

Image:

[image: see image]

html

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Report.aspx.cs" Inherits="Student_Report" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>







<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Student Report</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" style="text-align: center">
        <h1 style="font-family: 'Comic Sans MS'; text-align: center; font-size: xx-large;">Student Report
        </h1>

  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server">
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>


    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string strSQLconstring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ToString();
        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        //report path
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Report.rdlc");
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("sp_StudentData", strSQLconstring);
        adp.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        //object of Dataset DemoDataSet
        TWCL_OPERATIONSDataSet ds = new TWCL_OPERATIONSDataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds, "sp_StudentData");
        //Datasource for report
        ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds.Tables[0]);
        ReportViewer1.Width = 2000;

        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
    }
```

I've done some research and I can't seem to figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: Which line thrown the exception, are you attempting to upgrade `ReportViewer` from previous versions? Possibly you should look into web.config and package manager to ensure no conflict occurred.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, no exception was thrown and I've not upgrade reportviewer